# Dropzone.js with Laravel get 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone.js

I try to upload image with dropzonejs library. I have follow the documentation on dropzone but I get Internal Server Error.

html:

```
<form action="http://localhost/visitingcy/public/management/create-thing"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

Laravel php code:

```
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $getImages = $request->input('file');
        $count = 0;
        $images = array();
        foreach ($getImages as $img) {
            $imageURL = str_slug($newThing->title) . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $checkForDuplicate = DB::table('things_images')->where('url', '=', $imageURL)->get();

            while (!empty($checkForDuplicate)) {
                $imageURL = str_slug($newThing->title) . $count . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $checkForDuplicate = DB::table('things_images')->where('url', '=', $imageURL)->get();
                $count++;
            }
            $images[] = ThingImage::create(['url' => $imageURL]);

            //save file to public directory
            $img->move(base_path() . '/public/img/thing/gallery/', $imageURL);
        }
        return $images;
    } else {
        dd('there isnt file');
    }
```

Comment: Can you find more about the 500 error? Maybe with the developer tools in the browser or the laravel error logs in the storage folder?

Comment: in the laravel logs file I get: local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). It says for that foreach => foreach ($getImages as $img) because $getImages variable 
equals to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had used foreach but the dropzone upload each file individually so it doesn't need. The 500 error from the console is because I have another feature in my controller that has issue.